# Bridged networking does not work on VMWare Player 15.5

Tags: networking, vmware-player

If I use NAT I get connectivity between my guest OS and all other hosts on my network.  If I use Bridged networking I cannot connect from the host to guest os and my guest os cannot connect to any other host on my network.

My host is Windows 10 running on Dell XPS15-9560 laptop.  My guest os is ubuntu 19.10.

Does anyone know if this has been fixed in VMWare workstation pro?  I can upgrade if the pro version of VMWare will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this:   [Installing kubernetes breaks network connectivity.](https://serverfault.com/questions/1011009/installing-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-19-10-kills-network-connectivity)  I doubt this is due to VMWare Player.

It also doesn't seem to cause a problem on Ubuntu 18.04, so maybe a problem with 16.04 and 19.10 releases, or maybe just need different installation procedures with different Ubuntu versions.